# Customizing Swagger-ui to expose partial method from entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I am using swagger 2 with Spring-Data-Rest Application, All Possible services from entity is being expose, and many of them is not required. 
so I want to expose only GET methods of my entity.
Note -: Controller or service is not created for the entity.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new 
                    Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
                   .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                   .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                   .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using spring-fox for generating the swagger definition?

Comment: I am using only the configuration as shown above. I dont have much idea about this

Comment: this means you are using spring fox. You should see this in your dependencies (pom.xml or build.gradle).

Comment: And you are saying you don' have any controllers or service classes? Just entities? Are you using spring-data-rest?

Comment: Yeah, I am using spring-data-rest